# Case-insensitive abbreviations

Tags: insert-mode, abbreviations, word-processing

I use abbreviations extensively to make writing in languages other than English easier. For example, I have something like this set up for when I'm writing in Italian:

```
inoreabbrev perche' perché
inoreabbrev dopodiche' dopodiché
```

This way I can type the words above quickly without changing keyboard layout system-wide or using digraphs. Sadly these abbreviations don't work when the word is capitalized, like when it comes after a period.

Is there a way to way to force an abbreviation to trigger regardless of the case? Do I have to set up 2 abbreviations for every word or is there another way, like regexes or a special option?

Comment: I always thought that it would be good to use autocomplete for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [abolish plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish/). For your example you could use the following:

```
:Abolish perche{'} perché
```

It changes `perche'` to `perché`, `Perche'` to `Perché` and `PERCHE'` to `PERCHÉ`. For the second example:

```
:Abolish dopodiche{'} dopodiché
```

Comment: Ah, Tim Pope. If he's wrote a plugin for this, there's definitely no better option. Looks like I'll have one more of his plugins in my bundle folder then. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: I have created a vim-abolish substitution file for every accented word in Italian, should someone need it: https://gist.github.com/mrzool/f796b0b55b5783528915ac4f66095156

Answer (score 0):

I would have written an  `imap-<expr>` on `'` that tests the previous character, `e` and `E` would become `é` and `É`. And so on.

The caveat being when writing source code where `'` is a valid character on its own, and where we could have a single-quote after an `e`. We could check the current syntax in that case.

```
function! s:compose_if_match(accent, letters)
  let crt = getline('.')[col('.')-2]
  if crt =~? a:letters
    return "\<bs>\<c-k>".a:accent.crt
  else
    return a:accent
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <expr> ' <sid>compose_if_match("'", 'e')
inoremap <expr> ` <sid>compose_if_match("`", '[aeu]')
```

Honnestly, unless I don't have a French keyboard, instead of retro-actively fixing words automagically thanks to quotes and backticks, I'd rather hit backspace and fix the word by hitting the proper key which is also on the first row. I would understand that using `CTRL+K` on non-French keyboards is tiresome.